# What are the possible reasons this LP gets a lot harder when I change the cost of some variables?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I'm trying to solve a large LP using the `Gurobi` solver. It has 50K rows and 1.3M columns. NOTE that although the problem is MIP, I want to talk only about solving the simplex at the root node.

I found out that out of these 1.3M variables, there are ~10K variables that when I change their coefficient in the objective, have a dramatic effect on the difficulty of solving the simplex at the root node. If their coefficient is `1` (all with the same coefficient), the simplex is solved within 4 seconds. If their coefficient is `10` (again, all with the same coefficient), Gurobi spends 15 minutes trying to solve the simplex and still doesn't succeed.

Why is this happening? Does it have to do with degeneracy? Ill conditioning? Scale? If you can point out a possible direction to explore it would be great.

---

cost = 1, simplex finds a solution instantly!

```
Found heuristic solution: objective 23054.663666
Variable types: 295 continuous, 1278400 integer (1277734 binary)
Root simplex log...
Iteration    Objective       Primal Inf.    Dual Inf.      Time
       0    6.6627962e+02   1.192000e+03   0.000000e+00     89s
    2429    1.3467620e+04   1.137112e+03   0.000000e+00     90s
    2973    1.3838855e+04   0.000000e+00   0.000000e+00     91s
Root relaxation: objective 1.383885e+04, 2973 iterations, 4.26 seconds
```

---

cost = 10, simplex doesn't find a solution :(

```
Found heuristic solution: objective 25501.568169
Variable types: 295 continuous, 1278402 integer (1277736 binary)
Root simplex log...
Iteration    Objective       Primal Inf.    Dual Inf.      Time
       0    1.0812209e+03   1.233188e+03   0.000000e+00     83s
    7437    1.8077371e+04   1.554334e+05   0.000000e+00     85s
   10137    1.8151933e+04   5.576900e+04   0.000000e+00     90s
   11814    1.8207780e+04   1.029386e+05   0.000000e+00     95s
   13095    1.8222274e+04   4.753930e+04   0.000000e+00    100s
   14319    1.8237355e+04   2.851513e+05   0.000000e+00    105s
   15452    1.8250858e+04   9.594756e+04   0.000000e+00    110s...
```

Comment: Hmmm I think this will be quite hard to diagnose without knowing quite a lot more about the problem structure. (Also FYI I edited your post to add the “mixed-integer-programming” tag, as your model includes continuous and integer variables.)

Comment: @DavidM. - sorry, I reverted your changes as I was intentionally talking only about the LP simplex solving at the root node. I edited and made it clearer

Comment: @ihadanny Oops—thanks for correcting me!

Comment: @denis - by default gurobi always tries barrier, primal and dual simplex concurrently, and stops when the first one finishes. I deliberately enforced only simplex as I saw that in the "easy" case this is the winning method... thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3):

Ill-conditioning is unlikely to be the culprit, since you are changing objective coefficients and not constraint coefficients. Degeneracy is a possibility. Changing the objective coefficients of a subset of variables may change the simplex solution sequence (if you are using primal simplex) from one portion of the feasible region (where vertices are nondegenerate) to another (where vertices tend to be degenerate). That's a possibility, but by no means a certainty.

I'm not a Gurobi user, but if Gurobi gives you a choice of algorithms for the root relaxation (primal simplex, dual simplex, interior point, ...), you might experiment with changing the algorithm in the difficult case and see if one algorithm gets you better performance. That does not answer the "why" question, but perhaps renders it moot.

Comment: thanks! Your answer made it clear to me that I have to add these important details: I'm using dual simplex, as by default Gurobi tries primal, dual and barrier (all in parallel) - and I saw that dual is the one that succeeds in the easy case. Another thing - if degeneracy is the culprit, why would changing from one constant value (1) to another constant value (10) change the situation?

Comment: Dual simplex doing best in the "easy" case does not guarantee it is also best in the "hard" case. Changing 1 to 10 would make no difference if *all* the variables' objective coefficients were being changed. Changing coefficients of *some* variables may make them more (or less) attractive for entering the basis than they were before the change.